# Bootstrap-tour not initializing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

HTML:

```
<button id="#enrol-btn1">button</button>
```

JS:

```
var tour = new Tour({
steps: [{
    element: "#enrol-btn1",
    title: "Exam Enrolment",
    content: "First let's enrol to an exam"
}]
```

}).init().start(true);

I cannot get it to initialize on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P5fJ2/20/

What else do I need in order to get a basic example going? I looked through a few other questions on SO but couldn't fix this fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an (I guess) typo in your html:

```
<button id="#enrol-btn1">button</button>
```

should be

```
<button id="enrol-btn1">button</button>
```

for the Tour to match the element selector you provided in the step ("#enrol-btn1") .